# delete the records in sql based on satisfaction of 2 condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete the records in the table based on 2 condition.

This is my query :

```
delete from customer where productid not in (1,2,3,4,5) and manufacturerid not in ( 8,10)
```

The problem is I am able to see customer with productid 6,7,8 etc where manufacturerid is 8 and 10.

I want to delete all the product except id 1,2,3,4,5 which has manufacturerid 8 and 10 alone but my query is not working as expected.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Try this : DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE PRODUCTID NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5) OR MANUFACTURERID NOT IN ( 8,10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is actually a `NOT` with an `AND`:

```sql
DELETE C
FROM Customer C
WHERE NOT (C.productid IN (1,2,3,4,5) AND C.manufacturerid IN (8,10));
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your explanation you want to delete as follows with **OR** and not **AND**. This means that will will delete where either, or both, of the conditions is true.

```
DELETE FROM customer 
WHERE
  productid NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5) 
OR
  manufacturerid NOT IN ( 8,10) ;
```